# pandas json normalize not all fields from record path

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

I am trying to get just some of the fields of a record because I do not want to delete the not wanted columns afterwards but can't figure out how to do it. My real JSON has a lot more fields in the "countries" path, this is just an example.

Example JSON

```
data = [{'state': 'Florida',
             'shortname': 'FL',
             'info': {
                 'governor': 'Rick Scott'
             },
             'counties': [{'name': 'Dade', 'population': 12345},
                          {'name': 'Broward', 'population': 40000},
                          {'name': 'Palm Beach', 'population': 60000}]},
            {'state': 'Ohio',
             'shortname': 'OH',
             'info': {
                 'governor': 'John Kasich'
             },
             'counties': [{'name': 'Summit', 'population': 1234},
                          {'name': 'Cuyahoga', 'population': 1337}]}]
```

json_normalize

```
result = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data, 
    record_path='counties',
    meta=['state', 'shortname',
        ['info', 'governor']])
```

output

```
         name  population    state shortname info.governor
0        Dade       12345  Florida        FL    Rick Scott
1     Broward       40000  Florida        FL    Rick Scott
2  Palm Beach       60000  Florida        FL    Rick Scott
3      Summit        1234     Ohio        OH   John Kasich
4    Cuyahoga        1337     Ohio        OH   John Kasich
```

but I do not want the "population" in this example, I just want the name of the counties
I tried all kind of combinations in the meta attribute.

Comment: You could drop it: `pd.json_normalize(data, 'counties', ['state', 'shortname', ['info', 'governor']]).drop(columns='population')`

Comment: Sorry but as I wrote, that is what I want to avoid. I do not want to delete/drop the columns afterwards and it is not just one column like in my example there are about 20 columns I do not want